# How long to stay on a contract

Tags: software-industry, career-development

I have 3 years of experience, in 2 jobs - one for a year, second for 2 years. Now I'm in my 3rd job. Each one of them was a big step forward, but my current company was not, contrary to what it was supposed to be, and I'm not happy about it.

It would be great to stay for half a year, learn as much as I can, then take a career break for some time to travel the world (while I still can), go back and start looking for a new job. Or start looking while on a break.

I would stay longer here, but - I have less money than I was told (no travel fees), I work from a different place, I have my whole team in a different place, I am not paid for overtime (I would happily work over 40h/week, because I don't have paid vacations). So even though I learn a lot, I'm not happy with my situation. In half a year, before taking a break, my cv would look like this:

```
1st job - 10 months
2nd job - 2 years
3rd job - 6 months
```

My current job is a contract, I could easlily justify all changes, but still - will it be considered a job hopping? Is it a good decision? Will the resigning after 6 months, and/or taking a break later (3 - 6 months, but with still learning in the meantime), affect my future career?

Comment: "*Is it a good decision?*" No one here can tell you that. Aside from it depending on whether the contract or job (you seem to use the terms interchangeably but they mean very different things) was intended to be temporary or not, we can't tell you how to plan your career. Some of your other questions have previously been covered on the site and can be easily found via the [search](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=).

Comment: The development field moves at a rapid pace as you know.  It will be tough for you to *travel the world* for 3 to 6 months and stay current.  If you need a long break, I would suggest closer to 1 month.

Comment: If you're working a contract, you need to learn to make the other side keep their promises. They say they'll pay for travel, you don't travel without pay. Same for over-time. What do you have to lose, you're considering leaving anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly contract jobs are meant to be temporary, it is 100% perfectly OK to look for something permanent or better while in a temp position.

Have you addressed your concerns with the firm you work for?  If you're paid hourly (like most contract jobs are in the US) then you should be able to collect overtime, are you simply not being offered the opportunity.

If I was reviewing your work experience I would understand that you're in a contract position and are looking for something with benefits.

Comment: It's a consultancy company, so after my project ends, they find me another project. Does that still count as a temp job?

Comment: Each job is with a different employer or are they all with the same employer?  If you've been with the same firm for a while, why not tell them that this position isn't working out for you and they will try to find something else?

@JoeStrazzere when I was a contractor last year I reported my time (signed by my manager) to the contracting firm and they sent me paychecks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a hiring manager, but I would hope that one would be understanding to the idea of leaving a job that didn't offer a stable environment to work in. If the question comes up during an interview as to why you left your last job, you can just tell them the company didn't honor some of their agreements in respect to pay and travel.

I worked as a contractor in the Middle East for three months before leaving due to issues with the company owner and payments. It never came up, but if it had I could have explained my grievances.